# Replacing tab with spaces to maintain n-space alignment

Tags: shell, tabs, whitespace

I am trying to automatically compare two sets of files containing data organised into columns. There are three main issues that seem to be making this tricky:

1. Column ordering is different between set A and set B
2. Set A uses tabs, set B uses spaces
3. In Set A, some columns contain blanks, Set B, they contain a default value.

I have attempted to do some simple shell scripting to rearrange Set A into correctly ordered columns, e.g. `awk '{print substr($0, 10, 10) substr($0, 20, 10)}` etc, but the use of tabs within this set of files means that columns start with an inconsistent character number.

I think the simplest solution would be to replace tabs with spaces, and then use an `awk` to rearrange the data as above. How should I go about replacing a tab with a number of spaces equal to the number needed to reach the next tab stop (for the purposes of this, lets assume 8).

Replacing a tab with a set number of spaces obviously won't work, as I've tested below.

```
$ echo "A\tB\nA \tB\nA  \tB\nA   \tB\n" > test
$ cat test
A       B
A       B
A       B
A       B
$ cat test | sed 's/\t/    /g'
A    B
A     B
A      B
A       B
```

Obviously, this could be solved by writing some code that identified what position at tab character is at, and then filling a suitable number of space characters to achieve alignment, but it seems like there should be a much simpler solution that this that I'm probably missing. (Or open every file in vim and use `:retab`, but there must be a better option!)

Note: I am unable to `column` to rearrange data because of the blanks that exist in some datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have spaces before tabs you can use this sed:

```
sed $'s/ *\t/    /g' test
A    B
A    B
A    B
A    B
```

This will also replace 0 or more spaces before tab by 4 spaces.

Comment: Knew it would be something straightforward - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the following awk script :

```
BEGIN {
  tabSize = 8;
}
{
  str = $0;
  idx = index(str, "\t");
  while (idx > 0) {
    left = substr(str, 0, idx);
    right = substr(str, idx + 1);
    spaces = sprintf("% " ((tabSize + 1) - (idx % tabSize)) "s", "");
    str = left spaces right;
    idx = index(str, "\t");
  }
  print str;
}
```

You can execute this command :

```
cat test | awk -f tab2spaces.awk
```

This script will work with any content.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything.